# python compute bandwidth, error packet rate and transfer rate between a client and a server app

Tags: python, sockets, udp, bandwidth, iperf3

I am developing the python code for a client and a server.
This code must mimic the transmission of a stream (UDP stream) from server one or more clients , while each client has to compute some "metrics"about it, such as bandwidth, packet error rate and transfer rate in MB/GB, something very similar to the udp test of iperf3.

Unfortunately i haven't find some python code for it (except for a buggy wrapper of iperf3 and some other very buggy code around) Can you suggest me some libraries or code snippets which execute iperf3 functionalities?

Anyway,my server spawns a thread which generates a UDP stream towards client using **socket** library, while a client, which has an open udp socket,spawns a thread for receiving the stream and computes those metrics. Do you have any suggestion on the implementation? are threads good or is there something better for this task?

Can you suggest me how to compute those metrics? 
If you can post some code snippests i would be very thankful to you

Comment: You definitely don't need threads on the client side. Each client receives a single stream and can compute the metrics by measuring the number and size of UDP packets received per time interval. On the server side, you could use a separate thread per client, but it is overkill. It is easier to send a UDP packet at regular time intervals to each client socket. No need for threads.

Comment: thank you forn your suggestion, I have removed threads from client and I am working on removing them on the server as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea yet on how to process UDP packets, since the library "socket" buffers all the received packets introducing a delay to applicative level, making difficult to measure bandwidth

Comment: UDP sockets (created using "socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)") will deliver packets to the application as fast as the application is willing to read them.  As long as your application reads the socket as soon as it becomes readable (e.g. using blocking reads), there will be no significant additional delays due to buffering in the kernel. If even this small delay is too much for you, consider a user-space stack, for example DPDK (https://www.dpdk.org/).